# How to generate the 'amp_url_signature' value to update AMP cache

Tags: amp, openssl

I want to update the AMP cache of my website, and created the private key for my server by following Google's directions.

```
$ openssl genrsa 2048 > private-key.pem
$ openssl rsa -in private-key.pem -pubout >public-key.pem
```

However, I don't know how to generate the hash of 'amp_url_signature' to complete the URL

```
https://example-com.<cache.updateCacheApiDomainSuffix>/update-cache/c/s/example.com/article?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=<ts_val>&amp_url_signature=<sig_val>
```

This is, I do not know how to obtain <sig_val>

I tried with PHP

```
function urlsafe_b64encode($string) {
    return str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-','_',''), base64_encode($string));
}
$timestamp=time();
$signatureUrl = '/update-cache/c/s/amp.mydomain.com/amp/page-url?amp_action=flush&amp_ts='.$timestamp;
$pkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_private("/full/path/to/private-key.pem");
openssl_sign($signatureUrl, $signature, $pkeyid, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
openssl_free_key($pkeyid);
$signature = urlsafe_b64encode($signature);
echo $signature;
```

But $signature is empty.

Is there any other scripting language to obtain 'amp_url_signature'? Am I doing something wrong?